# How to sort json array by date in laravel php

Tags: php, json, laravel, sorting

Hi i'm using PHP laravel to generate a JSON response. This is my function which will generate this response

```
public function getReport($employeeCode){
    $postData = Input::all();

    $companyName = $postData['company_name'];
    $date = $postData['date'];
    $month = $postData['month'];
    $year = $postData['year'];
    $visitReason = $postData['visit_reason'];

    (database query applied here which gets data in $report)

    $countReportSize = count($report);
    $allDatas = [];
        for($i = 0; $i < $countReport; $i++)
        {
            $date = $report[$i]->day;
            $month = $report[$i]->month;
            $year = $report[$i]->year;
            $desc = $report[$i]->description;

            $countDateSize = explode(',',$date);
            $countMonth = explode(',',$month);
            $countYear = explode(',',$year);
            $countDescription = explode(',',$desc);

            for($j= 0; $j < count($countDateSize); $j++)
            {
                $data = [
                    'inquiry_id' => $report[$i]->inquiry_id,
                    'date' => $countDateSize[$j].'-'.$countMonth[$j].'-'.$countYear[$j],

                ];
                array_push($allDatas, $data);
            }
        }
        return response()->json($allDatas);
}
```

Now this function will generate given below JSON response, The question is how to sort it by date ?

```
[
{
"inquiry_id": "2",
"date": "18-03-2018"
},
{
"inquiry_id": "2",
"date": "15-03-2018"
}
]
```

I need to sort this response by date like this :

```
[
{
"inquiry_id": "2",
"date": "15-03-2018"
},

{
"inquiry_id": "2",
"date": "18-03-2018"
}
]
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: People would have it easier to help you if you provided some [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code that generated those JSON responses.

Comment: Hi hamza - I don't think the original code snippet is really necessary.  All you want to know is how to edit / sort the response, right?

Answer (score 0):

Convert the JSON to an array with $myArray = json_decode($json_info, true);

and then use

```
$date = array_column($myArray, 'date');
        array_multisort($date, SORT_ASC, $myArray);
```

And now $myArray will be sorted by date ascending,

Comment: i have tried your solution but it's not sorting whole date i mean to say that only day is sorted but month is not sorted . This is the response

`[
    {
        "inquiry_id": "3",
        "date": "05-08-2018"
    },
    {
        "inquiry_id": "2",
        "date": "15-04-2018"
    },
    {
        "inquiry_id": "2",
        "date": "18-05-2018"
    },
    {
        "inquiry_id": "2",
        "date": "21-03-2018"
    },
    {
        "inquiry_id": "2",
        "date": "23-06-2018"
    }
]`

Comment: $date = array_column($myArray, 'date');
$date = strtotime($date);
        array_multisort($date, SORT_ASC, $myArray);

Comment: This error shows up 
strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: @hamza in this part of your code, add this
$data = [
                    'inquiry_id' => $report[$i]->inquiry_id,
                    'date' =>strtotime($countDateSize[$j].'-'.$countMonth[$j].'-'.$countYear[$j]),
];

Then run this again:
$date = array_column($myArray, 'date');
array_multisort($date, SORT_ASC, $myArray);

foreach ($myArray as $date_sorted) {
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $date_sorted['date']);
}

THere's an easier way to do this in laravel by the way, if you want to take that approach.